# $* is no longer supported as of Perl 5.30

Tags: regex, perl

We are moving from an old unix server with perl 5.8.8 to a new server with Perl 5.32.
We have a script that starts with following lines:

```
eval "exec /usr/local/bin/perl -S $0 $*"    
    if $running_under_some_shell;
                        # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.    
                        # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_]+=)(.*)/ && shift;    
                        # process any FOO=bar switches

$[ = 1;                 # set array base to 1
$, = ' ';               # set output field separator
$\ = "\n";              # set output record separator
```

The script doesn't work.
For the line `"eval "exec /usr/local/bin/perl -S $0 $*""` we get:

```
$* is no longer supported as of Perl 5.30 at /usr/local/ccmngr/bin/check_log.pl line 12.
```

If I remove the `$*` from `eval` line, we get the following for line `$[ = 1;`:

```
Assigning non-zero to $[ is no longer possible at /usr/local/ccmngr/bin/check_log.pl line 20.
```

If anybody has an idea and like to share, it will be great help.

Comment: Going from 5.8 to 5.30 is a long way, and your going to need to update your scripts to not depend on deprecated functionality.

Comment: `use diagnostics`

Answer (score 6):

These two should not have been used for a while.

Related to that use of `$*`, [perlrun for `-S`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-S) explains its convoluted usage and rationale.  In short,

> Typically this is used to emulate `#!` startup on platforms that don't support `#!`.

So I'd first try to just get rid of that line, since reasons for it may be entirely historical, and use the normal `#!/path-to-perl;` (seems to be `#!/usr/local/bin/perl;`), or if you needed to trigger the version of Perl that is first in your path (doesn't seem to be the case) use `/usr/bin/env`. See the linked docs. <sup>†</sup>

As for `$[`, the [perlvar for `$[`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5B) says

> This variable stores the index of the first element in an array, and of the first character in a substring. The default is 0, but you could theoretically set it to 1 ... As of Perl v5.16.0, it is implemented by the `arybase` module.

However, even as the quote above is from the most recent `perldoc`, the `arybase` isn't available anymore, neither as core nor via `CPAN`. One can always get the package from CPAN (the most recent version appears to be for 5.28) and install it and keep fingers crossed ... but that's not really promising. Instead, [Array::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Base) does exist and work per its synopsis (checked on 5.32).

(I'd really rather recommend to use 0-based arrays in a Perl script but I don't know whether it's feasible to change that in your program.)

More, you may well need to (carefully) rework quite a bit more, jumping from 5.8 to 5.32.

---

<sup>†</sup> It may be that the compiler is confusing that `$*` as a (removed) regex variable and complaining about that, since `$*` there is meant to be used by a `csh` shell (so perl shouldn't have a problem with it). If true, that may be possible to fix somehow.

But regardless, it's far better to just remove it if it's not anymore needed all these years later.

Comment: I don't think arybase changes anything. Installing it seems to be a bit of a hassle (it's not core anymore, and `cpanm arybase` doesn't work (at least on my Perl 5.32)). Even if it could be installed, I'm not sure it would help.

Comment: However, [`Array::Base`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Base) might be a reasonable alternative.

Comment: @Dada I've never used it but the linked docs show the intended usage (in synopsis, and confirm it later discussion)?  (I realize my tests was on 5.16! will try it on a newer version....)

Comment: As I understand the docs you linked for `arybase`, it doesn't explain how to use this module at all, beyond doing `$[ = 1`. Note the lack of `use arybase` from the doc. I feel like all it's saying is "the magic of `$[` is handled by the `arybase` module, which is implicitly loaded whenever you use `$[`". Anyways, I've never heard of this module before today, so I'm definitely not an expert ;-)

Comment: @Data -- you're right!  Even though this is a quote from the most recent docs, `arybase` isn't available anymore.  Neither as core nor on cpan.  (It's "skipped.")  Thank you! Updating answer...

Comment: I feel like that is *not* what the docs say about $[ ... I focused on `Its use is highly discouraged` and `As of Perl v5.30.0, or under use v5.16, or no feature "array_base", $[ no longer has any effect, and always contains 0. Assigning 0 to it is permitted, but any other value will produce an error.`

Comment: Regarding `$*`, it is used as a shell variable, which thus contains all arguments of the program, rather than as the Perl variable to control regexes.

Comment: @Dada Of course. Or at least, that's what they originally *thought*. But it probably was always interpolated in that string. `$0` worked because it is the same in Perl. It's probably a bug in the original script

Comment: Actually, I'm super confused about `$*`: I'm 99.999% sure it's meant as the shell variable that refers to all the arguments of a program (that would be `"@ARGV"` in Perl), but the statement modifier `if $running_under_some_shell` is not valid Shell unless I'm mistaken... So.... This line reads to me like it's a mix of Shell and Perl, and I don't know what to make of it. As you say @TLP, probably a bug in the original script indeed (funny how a script was bugged for 20 years and nobody noticed! :D).

Comment: @Dada, Just installed `Array::Base` on 5.32 (`cpanm -i ...` and it just worked), and used it by its synopsis and it works. Updated the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Dada I read in perldoc perlrun just now that using `if 0` is a thing in shebang manipulation. Probably during the pre-strict days, this was a way to do the same and leave a comment about it at the same time. Yuk.

Comment: Right, nevermind, this line was actually not bugged. It's just that the `if $running_under_some_shell` is at the next line, and thus ignored by the Shell. Ok, so the fix for the first line (`$*`) seems to be, according to [Perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.34.0/perlrun#-S) to write instead `eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'` and `if 0;` at the next line.

Comment: @Dada -- the `$*` was needed for `csh`, so if they have that shell then they can't do that.  But, I think that they can just get rid of it altogether.   This was an old hack to use a perl script of a sort of an interpreter for other programs etc.  They probably don't need that nowadays

Comment: @Dada You mean to say that first line is not Perl code? Its just something the shell reads while looking for the shebang, and Perl ignores it because of the second line.

Comment: @TLP "_first line is not Perl code_" -- See my comment above... and an update in the asnwer

Comment: @TLP Yes, that `if 0` (or `if $non_existing_variable` here) was just a false.  `perlrun` explains it.  I've updated.  What threw me off originally was their mentioning of line 12 in the error...

Comment: Re "*What threw me off originally was their mentioning of line 12 in the error...*", They probably have someone kind of comment block first. But bad of them posting the output of a program that's different from the one they posted.

Comment: @ikegami yeah, that what's I thought, and yes they should've trimmed it down.  It even crossed my mind that putting it at a beginning may remove that problem since `$*` isn't perl's at that place and perhaps the compiler can recognize that within first X lines or some such.  (It must be complaining about the regex `$*` in fact, which has been thrown out.)  But it doesn't work...  But of course, in either case they should just remove it since it almost surely isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the following lines first:

```perl
eval "exec /usr/local/bin/perl -S $0 $*"    
    if $running_under_some_shell;
                        # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.    
                        # (remove #! line above if indigestible)
```

The `$*` is not intended to be used by Perl. If this program is run by `perl`, these lines do nothing because `$running_under_some_shell` is false.

But if it's run by a shell, the first line ends up getting executed, and it's meant to get `perl` to execute the script. These lines are there to make `./script` work on machines that have no shebang (`#!`) support.

**Fix**

Unless you're running this script on some weird ancient machine, you can avoid the issue by replacing those lines with

```sh
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

---

`$[` is no longer supported.

- 5.12 (2010): Assignment to `$[` was deprecated.
- 5.16 (2012): Assignment to `$[` was disabled unless `use feature 'array_base';` was used.
- 5.16 (2012): Assignment to `$[` now only effects the current lexical scope.
- 5.28 (2018): The release notes warn that assignment to `$[` will be removed in 5.30.
- 5.30 (2019): Assignment to `$[` (and `use feature 'array_base';`) was removed.

Plenty of warning was given. You need to convert your code to expect 0-based arrays.

In the meantime, here are two workarounds you could use.

**Workaround 1**

Replace

```perl
$[ = 1;
```

with

```perl
use Array::Base +1;
```

I would consider this a *temporary* fix. I wouldn't rely on this to keep working.

**Workaround 2**

Install Perl 5.28 (or earlier, e.g. using `perlbrew`), and replace

```perl
$[ = 1;
```

with

```perl
# ***** WARNING: THIS STOPS WORKING IN PERL 5.30 *****
no warnings qw( deprecated );
use feature qw( array_base );
$[ = 1;
use warnings qw( deprecated );
```

Again, this is just to buy you time to adjust your program to use 0-based arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you have vital code that is written in Perl, then you shouldn't be running it using the system Perl - as you've seen, this can prevent you from upgrading your operating system.

Instead, you should have your own installation of Perl which is a version known to work with your code. [`perlbrew`](https://metacpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/view/script/perlbrew) is a handy tool for doing this.

(But, yes, you should also look at using code that isn't quite as old as that!)